# this in equals method

Tags: java, this, equals

I am looking at the equals method, and I see `this` and I don't understand what it means...I do understand them when I see it in constructors and some methods but its not clear to me when they are in equals method something like this:

`(obj == this)` ...what does this mean here ? where does it come from ?

I understand when it says something like this.name = name;

from a method like this

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (obj == this) {
        return true;
    }
    if (obj == null || obj.getClass() != this.getClass()) {
        return false;
    }
```

sorry it might be a duplicate but I couldnt find anything...

Comment: What does it mean in a constructor like in your example? It means exactly the same thing in a method.

Comment: It means the exact same thing in any method as it does in a constructor.

Comment: `==` Checks if the values of two operands are equal or not, if yes then condition becomes true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to look how this is called:

```
someObject.equals(someOtherObj);
```

This invokes the `equals` method on the instance of `someObject`. Now, inside that method:

```
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
  if (obj == this) { //is someObject equal to obj, which in this case is someOtherObj?
    return true;//If so, these are the same objects, and return true
  }
```

You can see that `this` is referring to the instance of the object that equals is called on. Note that `equals()` is non-static, and so must be called only on objects that have been instantiated.

Note that `==` is only checking to see if there is **referential** equality; that is, the reference of `this` and `obj` are pointing to the same place in memory. Such references are naturally equal:

```
Object a = new Object();
Object b = a; //sets the reference to b to point to the same place as a
Object c = a; //same with c
b.equals(c);//true, because everything is pointing to the same place
```

Further note that `equals()` is generally used to also determine **value** equality. Thus, even if the object references are pointing to different places, it will check the internals to determine if those objects are the same:

```
FancyNumber a = new FancyNumber(2);//Internally, I set a field to 2
FancyNumber b = new FancyNumber(2);//Internally, I set a field to 2
a.equals(b);//true, because we define two FancyNumber objects to be equal if their internal field is set to the same thing.
```

Comment: this totally cleared my confusion..thank you so much for taking the time to explain!

Comment: @Dana Be sure to accept one of the several good answers here, to ensure people feel awarded for helping you in the future!

Answer (score 5):

`this` is the current Object instance. Whenever you have a non-static method, it can only be called on an instance of your object.

Answer (score 4):

You are comparing two objects for equality.  The snippet:

```
if (obj == this) {
    return true;
}
```

is a quick test that can be read

> "If the object I'm comparing myself to is me, return true"

. You usually see this happen in `equals` methods so they can exit early and avoid other costly comparisons.

Answer (score 3):

`this` refers to the **current instance** of the class (object) your equals-method belongs to. When you test `this` against an object, the testing method (which is `equals(Object obj)` in your case) will check wether or not the object is equal to the current instance (referred to as `this`).

An example:

```
Object obj = this;
this.equals(obj); //true 

Object obj = this;
new Object().equals(obj); //false
```